# Regression with a ordinal scale dependent variable in the context of panel data

Tags: regression, time-series, ordinal-data, panel-data, odds-ratio

In my panel data I observe a quite large amount of different individuals for a fixed time duration. The time axis is fixed for every individual, i.e., I observe 20 time points for every individual.

The dependend variable is of kardinal scale but I choosed to transform it into ordinal scale. The reason for this transformation is due to the fact that I observe the case "-Inf" very often which can obviously not be included in any form of regression model. So I choose to split the axsis into intervals like (-Inf,-20000],(-20000,-10000],(-10000,0],(0,10000] and so on. Due to this transformation I actually observe a dependend variable of ordinal scale.

My first question in this context is: In what way a ordinal scaled dependend variable with time and individual specific variation can be modelled.

2nd: If I acutally do a "ordinal regression" how do I deal with a continuous explanatory variable. I already checked how small the cells get and I'll receive a very large multidimensional table with a lot of zeros and here and there a number from 4 upwards.

Kind regards

Comment: How is it possible to *observe* "-Inf"?

Comment: If one calculates the elasicity of demand. Since elasticity of demand ($E$) with price ($P$) and quantity ($Q$) equals $E = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial P}\frac{P}{Q}$ and the marginal revenue (MR) equals $MR = P + \frac{\partial P}{\partial Q}Q$ we can express $E$ in terms of $MR$ and $P$ as $MR = \frac{P}{MR-P}$. For every time $MR=P$ we observe $E$ = -Inf (or Inf) , this depends on the convention one makes about $E$ being negative or positive. The reasoning does not depend on the sign before $E$.

Comment: I assume there's an $E$ goes in here: $MR = \frac{P}{MR-P}$ somewhere. In any case, that looks like one is observing P and Q, and then calculating E.

Comment: One possibility would be to split into the cases where $\frac{\partial P}{\partial Q} = 0$ (I'm assuming Q isn't 0, let me know if that's wrong), and the cases where it isn't. The model may be somewhat different there, and then you don't need to categorize the whole thing.

Comment: In general the values of $Q$ are very small but I actually dont observe $Q$ I only got data on $MR$ and $P$. I thought about a possible categorization as well but then I would put all the cases where $\frac{\partial P}{\partial Q}<0$ into one group. Hence I would loose quite a big amount of information how $E$ behaves if $MR<P$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why would that put all those cases together?

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I thought you meant something like: $D=\begin{cases}
  0,  & \text{if }E = \text{-Inf/Inf} \Leftrightarrow MR = P\\
  1, & \text{if }E \neq \text{-Inf/Inf} \Leftrightarrow MR < P
\end{cases}$

Comment: Well, yes and no. I mean that when D=1, you'd have a suitable model for the original dependent variable as a continuous thing. When D=0, you'd do whatever was suitable there. Imagine writing a model for each of those rows.

Comment: But the dependend variable for the $D=0$ case would be a constant because MR is a constant (equals to $P$ all the time). How would I know if changes in $P$ do indeed have an impact on $E$? Another thing I'm not sure about is, that in models which concerns a ordinal dependend variable we need some grouping in order to do inference. If I observe a continous variable which is different for every individual, i.e., no grouping can be done, how can there be a fit? Maybe this leads to your suggestion to split the problem into two parts. But then I could not use $P$ as a explanatory variable.

Comment: What about a censored regression model. The variable $E$ can have values between -Inf and 0. In the context of a censored regression model I could use a dependend variable as you described. I'm not quite sure how this dependend variable would look because we assume that a latent variable determines some other variable. Since $E$ is determined by the difference of $MR$ and $P$ I would like to split like: $E$ if $MR\ne P$, and if $MR=P$ I would set something else. I cannot set 0 because $E$ itself ca be 0 since $MR$ itself can be -Inf/Inf.

Comment: "*But the dependend variable for the D=0 case would be a constant because MR is a constant (equals to P all the time).*" -- then it doesn't take a very big model to explain those values. I'm not sure of their value to your model otherwise. If you can make your subsequent suggestion work, then it sounds like it might be better.

Comment: The problem of the $D=0$ case relates to other variables which should be checked for their explanatory power. These "other" variables do indeed change between those $D=0$ cases. Since I really want to explain why the $D=0$ case occurs and when, i.e.,why the $D\ne 0$ case does not occur, the splitting of the problem seems not to work for me? The only thing I could acutally do is to do a regression model for the $D\ne 0$ case and then check if theres is a systematic difference in the independend variables between $D=0$ and $D\ne 0$.

Comment: I decided to do the following: Since $E$ depends upon the difference of $MR-P$ and will be -Inf if $MR=P$ and 0 if $MR=$-Inf I do a censored regression onto $y=\begin{cases}
  min(E)-\epsilon,  & \text{if }E < min(E)\\
  E, & \text{if }min(E)<=E<0\\ 0, & \text{if } E=0
\end{cases}$ The $\epsilon$ is choosen because $E=$-Inf corresponds to the case where $MR$ is equal to $P$. Hence min$(E)$ corresponds to the case where $MR$ is almost equal to $P$. The difference between those cases is quite marginal hence the $\epsilon$.